# Using Spring controllers inside Struts 2 to create a REST API

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, struts2

I have an application that uses Struts (version 2.3.16.1 GA) and Spring (version 3.2.4 GA) to inject objects into Actions, etc.

Now, I need to create a REST API for my app, and I can't use Struts' REST plugin for that, so I thought that since Spring was around already, I could just create Spring Controllers and then serve the API with Spring.

Say my current app runs in the `app` context on the server, so I will access it like this:

```
http://www.myserver.com:8080/app/some/path/anAction.action
```

And then that's how the whole flow of my current app works. Now what I'm intending to do, is to create a specific path which will be used exclusively by my REST API, so I tried making it work like this for example:

```
http://www.myserver.com:8080/app/api/users
```

I want to map `/api/*` to Spring, so all my controllers will live there.

Here are the relevant bits of my config that I did in order to accomplish this.

**`web.xml`:**

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts-prepare</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts-execute</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts-prepare</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts-execute</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest-api</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.myapp.spring.SpringApplicationConfiguration</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>rest-api</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**`struts.xml`:**

```xml
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/api/*"/>
```

**`SpringApplicationConfiguration.java`:**

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan( basePackages = {"com.myapp.controller"})
@Import( {BaseConfig.class, DataBaseConfiguration.class})
public class SpringApplicationConfiguration {}
```

**`UserController.java`:**

```java
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService service;

    @RequestMapping(value="/users", method=GET)
    @ResponseBody public List<User> list(@RequestParam(defaultValue = "25") int limit, @RequestParam(defaultValue = "1") int offset,  @RequestParam String filter ) {
        return service.list(limit, offset, filter);
    }
}
```

That's all the configuration I think I should have. Now, I start the server, login into the app (so check that Struts keep working fine), then try to send a GET request into my REST endpoint, and here are the logs:

**Logs:**

```
INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (MSC service thread 1-2) FrameworkServlet 'rest-api': initialization completed in 8939 ms
INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /app
INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS018559: Deployed "app.ear"
INFO  [com.app.web.filter.SignOnFilter] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-5) Redirecting to signon: /signon.action?redirectUri=index.action
WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-3) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/app/api/users] in DispatcherServlet with name 'rest-api'
```

Comment: +1, I like this question :) But are you showing it all ? What is SignOnFilter that is there in the log but not in the code ?

Comment: Why you cannot use S2 rest plugin?

Comment: @AleksandrM I can't use it because a per my understanding, it relies on convention-plugin, and that will require a huge refactoring to the current code in order to make it work that way

Comment: @AndreaLigios SignOnFilter just does some authorization logic when the  I sign on into the app. I did sign up here, but I just did it to test that the regular flow was still working. The call to the rest-api servlet should not go through that filter. That may just be adding extra noise to the question but is not necessary in the regular flow of the REST request

Answer (score 0):

No mapping is because you didn't map it correctly

```
@RequestMapping(value="/api/users", method=GET)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that one already but I get exactly the same warning that I posted on the original question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in defining your pattern in struts.xml.
change

```
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/api/*"/>
```

to

```
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/api/.*"/>
```